# WSGI Middleware for OAuth authentication

Tags: python, oauth, wsgi, middleware, flask

I have build a very small web application using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). Now I would like to add very basic authentication to the site (I don't need authorization). As Flask does not support auth&auth out of the box, I'd like to plug in a WSGI middleware doing this job. The web-app is only used by roughly 10 people, all of them are on Facebook. So I'd like to use Facebook's OAuth interface.

I've quickly looked through [the wsgi.org list of WSGI Middleware](http://wsgi.org/wsgi/Middleware_and_Utilities) and noticed two things: The available middleware is either quite complex to use, or it's already very dated.

I have found the following packages:

- [wsgiauth](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/wsgiauth/) -- It's dated. Last update is of 2006 and I cannot find any online docs
- [authkit](http://authkit.org/) -- Seems very nice, but does not support OAuth
- [barrel](http://lukearno.com/projects/barrel/) -- Seems to only support `BASIC` and Form based auth. It's also a bit dated (latest release is 2008)
- [webmodules](http://pythonweb.org/projects/webmodules/) -- Only supports `BASIC` auth

Given this list, I'd say that AuthKit is the most interesting. Alas, it does not support OAuth. I will most likely go ahead and give it a shot. But, while I'm doodling around, I'm curious to see if there is anyone around who has a better solution lying around...

Comment: Not a pro at authentication, but does dated middleware suggest that using it would be a security vulnerability, or that the middleware is rather mature/complete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look at [repoze.who](http://docs.repoze.org/who/1.0/), which is authentication framework for WSGI application with plugins available for:

- HTTP basic/digest
- Auth via HTML forms with storing auth ticket in cookies.
- [OpenID](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/repoze.who.plugins.openid/0.5.3)
- [OAuth](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/repoze-oauth-plugin/0.2)
- [LDAP](http://code.gustavonarea.net/repoze.who.plugins.ldap/)
- Many more I don't know...

Comment: Over the weekend I gave repoze.who a go. It looks very promising. Unfortunately, the OAuth plugin only offers the OAuth *server side*. For my project I would need client-side. I am thinking about creating a plugin myself. But, given the speed at which I work on my pet-projects, this may take a while ;)

Answer (score 7):

Flask has an [OpenAuth](http://packages.python.org/Flask-OAuth/) [extension](http://flask.pocoo.org/extensions/) that's written by the [Armin Ronacher](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-oauth) (Flask's author).  It provides Flask with support for Open Auth 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to authorize clients against facebook, why not use the python sdk they provide that includes an oauth interface found here https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk.