# What are some good web apps for learning Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm looking for apps source code with user registration, login, session, oauth and SQLAlchemy for learning Flask. I have looked at the source for flask.pocoo.org website and also some repos at Github. I believe there are more out there. Appreciate any pointer. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For login / registration / etc. see [Flask user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972999/flask-user-authentication)

For Oauth see [WSGI Middleware for OAuth authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648838/wsgi-middleware-for-oauth-authentication)

See [flask-sqlalchemy](/questions/tagged/flask-sqlalchemy) for info on that.

The [author of Flask also uses this site](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19990/armin-ronacher), so check out his questions and answers, as well as [his blog](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/).

Answer (score 7):

[Here](https://github.com/svenstaro/flamejam) is a decent-sized app based on Flask.

I'd also recommend searching github and bitbucket for the term 'Flask', or checking out [nullege's flask page](http://nullege.com/codes/search?cq=flask) (a valuable resource for finding how other projects use certain libraries).

Additionally, the author 'eats his own dog food' which makes [his github page](https://github.com/mitsuhiko) a great resource.

Finally, kennethreitz (an incredibly productive python developer) uses flask for some of his projects, which you can find [on his github page](https://github.com/kennethreitz).